# Delay por cada iteración en un bucle (python -django)

Tags: html, python, django

Cómo puedo utilizar la función time.sleep() en django?

Tengo una lista y al recorrerla quiero por cada fila a visualizar pueda retrasarla segundos. A esta lista la recorro en la plantilla.
Es nuevo para mí Django y realmente estoy confundida.

Cualquier aclaración y/o explicación será agradecida.
Muchas Gracias.

***Solución:***

No sé si es correcto publicar la solución aquí  pero la quiero compartir.

En stack overflow encontré este hilo:

[FadeIn - Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459751/adding-delay-on-loading-each-row-in-html-table)

y entre las respuestas el siguiente enlace :

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/SzLQD/)

Y fue todo lo que necesité debido a que lo pude adaptar a mi lista (filas de un dataframe) y agregar la función delay(). Funciona correctamente. 
Les agradezco a todos la información que me brindaron. He votado,  pero por mi reputación, no se hace visible.

Espero poder colaborar con ustedes también.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Yo no uso django, pero puede que esto te ayude: https://spapas.github.io/2018/05/08/django-reponse-add-delay/

Comment: Te agradezco. Lo estuve viendo pero no exactamente lo que estoy necesitando. Seguramente, tengo un error conceptual. Gracias!

Comment: Hola lau, bienvenida a [es.so], sleep bloquea la ejecución del hilo principal y por lo general no es buena idea usarlo. No se exactamente como muestra los items, pero por lo que deduzco intentas hacer algo así como una animación, esto es algo que podrías en el lado del cliente, simplemente usando javascript sería posible.

Comment: Gracias. Estuve probando con javascript y la verdad no me funciona bien. Por alguna razón sólo obtengo con delay la primera iteración y luego nada :/. De igual manera, es la aclaración que necesitaba porque mi duda principal era si existía algo más sencillo propio de Django. Gracias!

Comment: Para que quieres retrasar como dice FJSevilla vas a bloquear el hilo principal y esto te puede dar timeout en el cliente explicate mejor y agrega un ejemplo así te podemos ayudar mejor

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @lau? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero de todo bienvenida a StackOverflow.

Principalmente, he estado buscando información, y si solo buscas "`python` y `django`", salen cosas relacionadas con puro `Python`:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-sleep-command-syntax-example/

O bien como realizar demoras de peticiones HTTP como nuestro compañero @Saelyth comentaba.

O finalmente artículos mas complejos sobre demora en peticiones a nivel de servicios en el servidor como en el siguiente enlace:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084367/django-sleep-pauses-all-processes-but-only-if-no-get-parameter

Todo esto es backend.

Creo que por descarte y corrígeme si me equivoco lo que buscas realizar, no es a nivel backend sino frontend, y me apoyo en ese `tag` de la pregunta "HTML" y esa palabra "visualizar"

Esto supone una gran diferencia. Si es algo visual o a nivel de front-end , es mas fácil de lo que crees y voy a darte algunas ideas.

Si hasta aquí, sigues creyendo que no es visual, igual como dices en el comentario, es tema de concepto, y por ello te intentaré ayudar también.

Paremos a pensar por un segundo, si por "obligación" te sientes forzado a frenar esa carga, entonces es posible que necesites realizar esa acción  antes de ese punto, dejando así preparados los datos en el array y permites que el frontend (a la hora de cargar) fluya tranquilamente.

En este punto, lo que podrías buscar es ralentizar la carga del arreglo (`array`) en la plantilla, y tu objetivo es que esos datos a priori **no se vean**, por que quieres realizar algo entre medias.

Recuerda que tus datos ya van a estar cargados, solo manejas la visualización de los mismos.

Durante la carga inicial puedes realizar la siguiente lógica con `javascript`.

1. Ocultar los elementos donde se cargan los datos
2. Capturas el evento mediante `JS` que la pantalla ha terminado de cargar los datos
3. Con `Javascript` decir que elementos se van a mostrar durante la iteración de un bucle, recorriendo estos elementos.
4. Puedes agregar una pausa o `timeOut()`, para realizar una acción intermedia
5. Condicionar a que se realice una acción dependiendo del número de elementos cargados
6. Realizar animación de un elemento concreto

Y así, durante toda esta ejecución, vas controlando cada paso, cada cosa que quieres que hagan tus datos. Esto se llama edición o manejo del DOM con JavaScript, y puedes hacer uso de la famosa librería "JQuery" para apoyarte en la ejecución de estas tareas. Con funciones realmente simples puedes hacer cosas increibles.

```
https://jquery.com/
```

Por último solo quedarían peticiones asíncronas con `Javascript`, manejo de datos y peticiones en las que puedes realizar, no solo modificaciones visuales sino también de carga de datos.

No se me ocurren muchas mas alternativas, espero que sino te resuelve la pregunta, al menos puedas aclararnos un poco mas el tema ;)

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de código donde se realizan modificaciones a lo largo del tiempo con CSS y JS 
https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/

Espero que te sea de ayuda, y de otra forma, no dudes en editar tu pregunta y con toda esta información, definir un poco mas la situación.

---

**Documentación adicional:**

Te sugiero que cualquier tema relacionado con animaciones, empieces utilizando el código que menos hace sufrir una aplicación y es mas ligero, CSS.

Existen numerosas librerías, así como tutoriales para realizar efectos y animaciones realmente interesantes:

> https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Haciendo uso de `javascript` muy simple, puedes agregar una clase CSS e esta librería a un elemento haciendo que esos elementos se vean con una pequeña animación.

Si lo que necesitas es una interacción mas personalizada, específica, no queda de otra que picar código `Javascript`, y quizás apoyarte de alguna librería externa que realice la mayor parte del trabajo por ti, con funciones y animaciones como el siguiente enlace que te recomiendo:

> https://animejs.com/

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por esta respuesta. Me servirá perfectamente como guía para la lógica en javascript. No soy muy paciente con el front-end y por eso lo quería evitar. Mil gracias!

Comment: No hay de que, en ocasiones puede ser solo falta información o donde empezar a buscar. Si te vale la respuesta no olvides dar tu valoración positiva y que otros usuarios con el mismo problema puedan encontrar la solución. Para cualquier cosa te invito a volver y no dudes en preguntar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida a la comunidad. Sería mucho mas fácil si compartieras el codigo que llevas, que involucra el comportamiento que quieres hacer.

Django por defecto utiliza WSGI, el cual sirve las peticiones de manera síncrona, por lo tanto, al agregar un `time.sleep()` en algun método que se llame desde `views.py` debería bloquear todo el proceso, incluyendo la resolución de otras peticiones.

Por esto, es mala practica lo que quieres hacer, las peticiones en el servidor debiesen ser lo más rapidas posibles para dejar espacio para otros usuarios y acciones.

Por lo tanto, si lo que quieres es que el usuario sienta un retraso en como se muestran los resultados en la pagina web, no es necesario que apliques el delay en el servidor. Dado que esto se programa desde el front-end de la aplicación, es decir, desde el template HTML (en el caso de Django).

A modo de resumen, lo que deberías hacer consiste en aplicar una animación en como se renderizan esos resultados en pantalla. Teniendo todos los datos que quieres mostrar de una sola peticion al servidor (sin bloquear) como una lista, Iteras esta lista en el front-end con tu lenguaje preferido, te recomiendo JavaScript dado que no se si Django-template soporte animaciones especiales, haciendo todas los retrasos que quieras.

De todas maneras, la forma que estas pensando que consiste en aplicar un sleep, no sirve para lo que creo que quieres hacer, dado que django solo retorna una respuesta a una petición, por lo que al hacer un ciclo retrasado dentro de la resolución de esta respuesta solo retrasará la única respuesta que entregará, y por eso se obtiene el resultado que obtienes.

Otra solucion sería hacer N peticiones, donde se aplica el retraso a cada una de las peticiones, ahí con sleep te funcionará, pero insisto que eso es trabajo del front-end no del back-end.

Si estas aprendiendo, aprovecha de permearse de buenas practicas, después lo agradecerás.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias! Sí, creo que el principal error fue concentrarme time.sleep() y encontrar la forma de implementarlo en django. Voy a intentar con javascript nuevamente y volveré y compartiré el código. Les agradezco mucho su colaboración.